# How to keep files and apps when upgrading Windows 8 RP to RTM?

Tags: upgrade, windows-8-preview, windows-8

I have upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8 Release Preview. Now Windows 8 RTM has been released, but I received bad news - I can't upgrade to Windows 8 RTM.

So I think I will try this: From Windows 8 RP, I will install Win 7, after that I will install Windows 8 RTM. Will this work?

And my second question: Some people said that I could migrate my personal data but not the apps. Let's say I have Google Chrome installed with 80 bookmarks, and Winamp with 100 songs. After I migrate them, Google Chrome and Winamp will disappear but I will still have the 80 bookmarks and 100 songs. Is it true?

How about portable software like Eclipse?

Comment: Please help me...i need to know this ASAP. Thanks :)

Comment: Always back up your data to an external drive, never take anyone's word on what will happen when you do x, y or z.

Comment: Release Preview [can be](http://superuser.com/a/477969/138343) upgraded to RTM.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for your help, i dont think using "unsupported" method is a good idea, there might be a lot of problems after it. By the way, how about my questions? :D

Comment: @Moab i agree, thanks :D But i still need the answer to my question

Comment: @BlazeTama: The $40 Upgrade from Win8 Release Preview to RTM is fully supported, so you *can* upgrade and don't need to jump through hoops or do a clean install. I don't even think you can install Win7 from within Win8 RP to replace the latter - that sort of install path just doesn't make sense to me. If you clean install, obviously your installed apps are gone. If you upgrade, only your personal data will be migrated. Your songs shouldn't be touched, but I recommend backing up all personal data (including portable apps) anyway to an external drive before the upgrade.

Comment: @Karan So do you think upgrade is the best way in my case? Can i say that all of my apps in control panel will be uninstalled automatically? :D
Please answer my question so i can accept it. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @BlazeTama - Any installed application will have to be installed.  An application is not considered a personal file, and the only files that will be saved, will be those in My Documents, My Videos, ect.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help :D
How about if i have an image in D, will it be considered as personal file?will it be saved?

Comment: @Ramhound And how about if i add a library in My Documents, will it be saved? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the article [I linked to above](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/print/9228798),

> In follow-up answers, Microsoft said that users running Windows 8 Release Preview -- the newer of the two sneak peeks, shipped on May 31 -- can upgrade using the Windows.com upgrade tool and pay the $40.
>
> **However, the only bits that are retained during that upgrade are personal data files.** Other elements, including the applications, Windows settings and user accounts that migrate from Windows 7, do not.

I would recommend taking a backup of all important personal data in any case, since you don't want to end up frantically searching for something later, only to find that it's disappeared into the ether. Your apps won't be migrated so you'll need to reinstall them of course, but portable apps will continue to work as usual. Your personal data/files should be saved in the Windows.old folder, which you can access after the upgrade. More details can be found on [the Windows Upgrade site](http://windowsupgradeoffer.com).

If you want my opinion of whether an upgrade is the best way in your case, I'd actually recommend a clean install instead *using the cheap upgrade offer*. I mean, if your installed apps are not going to be migrated, what's the point? Might as well start afresh with a clean slate. Just take a backup of all your data (remember, for browser bookmarks you'll probably need to sync online or export to a file), then install using the steps outlined below (also from the same article):

> **Can I do a "clean" install?**
>
> Yes, you can, but not using the Upgrade Assistant. Instead, here's what you'll want to do to format the hard drive before installing Windows 8 Pro.
>
> Step 1: Use the Upgrade Assistant to qualify the PC and pay the $40.
>
> Step 2: When the "Install Windows 8" message appears, select "Install by creating media" to create a bootable USB flash drive or an .iso (a disk image) file.
>
> Step 3: Wait for the Assistant to download the Windows 8 Pro installation package and create the bootable media or .iso file. The flash drive must have 3GB or more of free space available.
>
> Step 4: Burn the .iso file, if that's the path you chose, to a blank DVD.
>
> Step 5: Use that USB drive or DVD to boot the PC.
>
> Step 6: When you get to the screen in Setup that asks, "Which type of installation do you want?' choose "Custom."
>
> Step 7: Select a disk partition for the OS in the next screen. At this point, you can create a new partition if there's enough space available, or reformat the drive.
>
> Step 8: Continue with the installation of Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: I want to ask you an additional question :D
Lets say i have an image in D and i do a Migrate, what will happen to my image?thanks :D

Comment: If you upgrade the OS installed in one partition, ordinarily it *shouldn't* touch other partitions at all.