# Windows 8 customer preview

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, updates

I have installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on windows Vista, I can I update all apps with Windows 8
released version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade/Update Windows 8 customer preview to normal version](http://superuser.com/questions/402875/upgrade-update-windows-8-customer-preview-to-normal-version). Also see [Will my apps and files be lost or MIGHT they be lost?](http://superuser.com/questions/477936/will-my-apps-and-files-be-lost-or-might-they-be-lost) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade to RTM from Consumer Preview in my experience.  You need to start again.